# Cell shading in RTF documents

Tags: rtf

Does anyone know the the rtf tags for applying a background color to a table cell?

I know the table structures:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0
 \trowd
 \clshdng10000\cellx1000
 \clshdng10000\cellx2000
 \clshdng10000\cellx3000
 cell 1\intbl\cell
 cell 2\intbl\cell
 cell 3\intbl\cell
\row}
```

But i have no idea as to how to apply the shading.

**UPDATED:** i added cell shading, but still cant set the shade color

Comment: When you read this, what was confusing?  http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm  It seems clear.  Can you identify specific questions or problems?

Comment: i can add `\clshdng` just before `\cellx1000` but setting the color is where i get stuck, it goes from `\clshdng0`(white) to `\clshdng10000`(black), but i only have RGB added to a color table

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to get the solution:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0
{\colortbl;\red188\green230\blue138;}<!--define a color table -->
  \trowd
  \cellx1000
  \clcbpat1\cellx2000 <!- \clcbpat1 = set background color -->
  \cellx3000
  cell 1\intbl\cell
  cell 2\intbl\cell
  cell 3\intbl\cell
 \row
}
```

You can string multiple colors together for example:

```
{\colortbl;\red188\green230\blue138;\red108\green030\blue038;}
```

And to use it you will call: `\clcbpat1` or `\clcbpat2`